# Script Optimization technics on build production for angular / other js frameworks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization, build, production

Since JavaScript Frameworks are evolving, we need to create more files to split codes into several files to better code manageability and co coding. However, more files means more http request over network. Is there any approach or tool to manage both for continuous release cycle. I mean better code management on development as well as minify / else and combine into single / less files on build and production. Can one tool covers those all or a set of tools required?

Comment: each builld tool like grunt,webpack,... has possibility to concat and minify files

Comment: I didn't use any of those before. Which one is popular.

Comment: I have used grunt and webpack, there is gulp and probably a lot of others.